# I am getting these error while executing in anonymous window

Tags: count, words

```
public class wordCounter {
    public  void submit(string[] args){
    String s = 'Big black bug bit a big black dog on his big black nose';
        List<string> a = s.split(' ');
        Map<String, Integer> words = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for (String str : a) {
            if (words.containsKey(str)) {
                words.put(str, 1 + words.get(str));
            }
             else {
                words.put(str, 1);
             }
         }
        system.debug(words);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, any luck with my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**First**: You aren't calling the class (properly). Try:

```
new wordCounter().submit(null);
```

**Second:** You are passing in an array of String (`String[] args`), but the code is not set up to handle a string array, just a single string.

**Third:** If you want the class to be useful, you need to pass in a string, not use one that's embedded in the method.

So you do something like this:

```
public  void submit(String arg){
    List<string> stringParts = arg.split(' ');
    //etc...
```

The call would then become:

```
new wordCounter().submit('Big black bug bit a big black dog on his big black nose');
```